# invalid conversion from `char' to `char*'

Tags: c

code is :

```
int main() {

    int i,last;
    char TXT[500];

    printf("Donnez un exemple ?\n");
    gets(TXT);
    last = strlen(TXT);

    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
        if (i==0){
            strcpy(TXT[1],TXT[0]);
        } else {
            strcpy(TXT[i-1],TXT[i]);
        }
    }

    getch();                        
    return 0;
}
```

error in line : `strcpy(TXT[1],TXT[0]);`

What is the cause of the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that you are not considering what your code does, but you're just hammering code blindly into the text editor and expecting miracle to come out.

Comment: "What is the cause of the problem ?" Let me guess. Lack of experience?

Comment: You don't understand the answers, but they answer the question you asked. If you want help solving your problem, then you need to define the problem. As it stands you just asked for an explanation of the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

The `strcpy` function takes two `char*` (technically, a `char*` and a `const char*`). Moreover, it is not allowed to pass `strcpy` overlapping buffers.

It looks like you wanted to write

```
TXT[i-1] = TXT[i];
```

(this would delete the leading character from the string).

```
for(i=1 /* one, not zero */ ; i<50 ; i++) {
    TXT[i-1] = TXT[i];
}
```

> Good, but I want to use `strcpy`. How?

You are not allowed to use `strcpy` without an intermediate buffer. If you must use `strcpy`, do it like this:

```
char TXT[500], TMP[500];
printf("Donnez un exemple ?\n");
fgets(TXT, 499, stdin);
strcpy(TMP, &TXT[1]); // Note that 'for' loop is no longer required
```

Comment: Good, but I want to use strcpy ? How ???

Answer (score 1):

`TXT` is an array of 500 characters.

So, `TXT[1]` and `TXT[0]` are individual characters (just one single letter).
`TXT[0]` is the very first character in the array.
`TXT[1]` is the second character in the array.

The function `strcpy` expects you to pass POINTER-to-characters (type `char*`) for both parameters.
And instead, you're passing a single character.

Can you explain what the purpose of this program is? 
Maybe we can help you fix it then.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean?
Possible until we understand the correct code ?

Comment: ***What problem are you trying to solve?***

Comment: 16 C:\Users\ELIAS\Desktop\INFORMATIQUE TP\iza7a.cpp invalid conversion from `char' to `char*'

Comment: **Why are you writing this program?  It makes no sense, and does not appear to do anything useful!**

Answer (score 1):

`TXT[i]` is of type `char`. But `strcpy` expects parameters of type `char*` since it operates on null-terminated strings. Hence the compilation error.

As for how to fix it, that depends on what your code is trying to do. Perhaps all you meant to do was

```
TXT[1] = TXT[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

**STRING FUNCTIONS WORKS ON STRING NOT ON CHARACTERS**

ARE YOU TRYING TO SWAP THE WORDS OR CHARACTERS ?

Comment: No need to shout.