# c++ copy array to array

Tags: c++, arduino

I have taken code from here [Webduino Network Setp](https://github.com/sirleech/Webduino/blob/master/examples/Web_Net_Setup/Web_Net_Setup.pde)

I added one more field.

```
 struct config_t
{
    ....
    ...
    .....
    byte subnet[4];
    byte dns_server[4];
    unsigned int webserverPort;
    char HostName[10]; // Added code Here..
} eeprom_config;
```

Snippet..

```
#define NAMELEN 5
#define VALUELEN 10
void setupNetHTML(WebServer &server, WebServer::ConnectionType type, char *url_tail, bool tail_complete)
{
    URLPARAM_RESULT rc;
    char name[NAMELEN];
    char value[VALUELEN];
    boolean params_present = false;
    byte param_number = 0;
    char buffer [13];
    .....
    .....
}
```

Added Lines to read date from web page and Wire to eeprom

Write to eeprom: ( Facing issue here, I need to copy value to eeprom_config.HostName[0] ... )

```
// read Host Name
if (param_number >= 25 && param_number <= 35) {
    // eeprom_config.HostName[param_number - 25] = strtol(value, NULL, 10);
    eeprom_config.HostName[param_number - 25] =  value ; // Facing Issue here..
}
```

and...

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    server.printP(Form_input_text_start);
    server.print(a + 25);
    server.printP(Form_input_value);
    server.print(eeprom_config.HostName[a]);
    server.printP(Form_input_size1);
    server.printP(Form_input_end);
}
```

Comment: That part of code doesn't make any sense. What is `eepromdata`? What is `invalue`? What is `value`? What data do you want to copy from where to where?

Comment: It doesn't need to be full code but it must be at least understandable what your problem is (A [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is definitely helpful). You didn't even write what you want to know.

Comment: Actual code is here: https://github.com/sirleech/Webduino/tree/master/examples/Web_Net_Setup

Comment: Don't write it in the comments but update your question. Still you don't specify what your problem is.

Comment: There is no code that looks like the snippet you have posted here. If you want help be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved.

Thanks , got idea from this post.
[invalid conversion from `char' to`char*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870943/invalid-conversion-from-char-to-char)

How !  changed

```
// read Host Name
if (param_number >= 25 && param_number <= 35) {
 // eeprom_config.HostName[param_number - 25] = strtol(value, NULL, 10);
    eeprom_config.HostName[param_number - 25] =  value ; // Facing Issue here..
}
```

changed to

```
// read Host Name
if (param_number >= 25 && param_number <= 35) {
eeprom_config.HostName[param_number - 25] = value[0];

}
```